# Proof, that $a \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let
$n \in \mathbb{N}^{+} \smallsetminus \{{1}\}$
and
$p = min\{p \in \mathbb{P} : p \mid n\}$.

Also, let
$a \in \mathbb{Z}$
and
$a^n \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$

I need to proof, that
$a \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.

It is a study task. Therefore, I wish to get some algorithm of solution of my problem.

Comment: Have you tried, like, anything?

Comment: @Sarah, I have no idea, how to start of proof.

Comment: Do you know fermats little theorem? <-- Read that

Comment: @Sarah, thank you, I will read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fermat's Little Theorem can be stated as, for any prime $p$ and coprime $a$ we have that $$a^{p-1}=1\pmod p$$
[These questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350170/gcd-fermat-little-theorem-and-euler-function?rq=1) are scattered around. Feel free to read on-line literature on the subject, it is not too hard to find.